# CSS div content size question

Tags: html, css

I have a structure like this

```
<div id="first">
  <div id="second">
    <div id="third">
      <div id="fourth">
        text
      </div>
      <div id="fourth">
        text2
      </div>
    </div>
    Some other stuff...
  </div>
</div
```

Here's the css for it at the moment:

```
#first {
 width:960;
}

#second {
 position:relative;
}

#third {
 position:relative;
 top:0;
 right:0;
}

#forth {
 position:relative;
 top:0;
 left:0;
}
```

Now I would like from the fourth items to stay in a row and from the third item to stay on the right side of the second div. The second div also has a width 960 like the first one.
What's the problem with this? why it isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited and should work(untested):

```
<div id="first">
  <div id="second">
    <div id="third">
      <div class="fourth"> <!-- changed to class -->
        text
      </div>
      <div class="fourth"> <!-- changed to class -->
        text2
      </div>
    </div>
    Some other stuff...
  </div>
</div> <!-- was missing closing bracket -->
```

And the style:

```
#first {
 width:960px; /* was missing px */
}

#second {
 position:relative;
}

#third {
 float:right  /* Makes the element float on the right side. Might want to clear in a later id/class to avoid quirks */
 position:relative;
 /* Removed redundant top:0; and right:0; */
}

.fourth {  /* Changed to class and fixed spelling */
 position:relative;
 /* Removed redundant top:0; and right:0; */
}
```

ID's should be used for elements that will only be used once.  Classes should be used for elements that can/will be used multiple times.

Comment: Thank for your comment. I think this will be one I needed. Also I have to ask you about class and id. Id is used once in the whole HTML page or in a div?

Comment: Your solution is good, but the "fourth" items are below each other, they should be in one line? please can you help me out in this?

Comment: You have to make sure that the .fourth items aren't too wide to fit next to each other.  All you should have to do is add display:inline; or float:left; to your .fourth class.  Each ID should only be used once throughout the whole html document.  Default positioning is relative as well, so those relative statements are really quite redundant as well.

Comment: Thank Freyr for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

First, 960 isn't a width. Without a units specifier, it's just a number. `960px` is a width.

Second, those other divs *are* positioned correctly, but their widths are 100% (the default), so they just look like they're stacked. The positioning is not noticeable because of that.

Edit: You also misspelled "#fourth" in your CSS selector.

Comment: Thank for your comment. Yes, it is forth. Sorry for it. :)

Answer (score 1):

For the forth div, why not use inline-div? [not sure it works on IE7 and below]..and im think the third can be floated to the right.
Also shouldn't you be using classes as opposed to multiple elements with the same id?

#third {
 float: right;
 position:relative;
 top:0;
 right:0;
}

#forth {
 display:inline-block
 position:relative;
 top:0;
 left:0;
}